# I'd like to increase the increment about python class

Tags: python

I want to get total numbers from def inc.

```
func.py
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        inc(self.i)

def inc(i):
    i += 1
    print(i)
    return i
```

Next  Another program call class B()

```
sub.py
class Sub(object):
   count = 0
    results = []
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pp = func.B(count)
    for row in l:
        #print(row)
        pp.read()
k = Sub()
```

But, I want to get number 5 instead of 1

Would you please let me know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Why have you defined `class Sub(object)` like a method? The code inside will only execute once.

Comment: Your question and code is not clear. What is `func`? What is `inc` supposed to do?

Comment: when do you get `1` instead of `5` ? Create minimal working code so we could copy and run it to see problem.

Comment: you have to use `self.i = inc(self.i)` to increase it.

Comment: I am still wondering why you do this p=0 then check if p==0 it will always true i guess

Comment: Hello
Thank you for a lot of comments here.
I am new in this world.  I am sorry for complicated matter.

I revised the code.  Actual codes are long codes.  So, I took required codes which I have to figure it out.

the func means func.py.  I'd like to get finally 5 return i of def inc(i) .
However, when I run class Sub(): by debug mode, the return i of def inc(i) is always 1.  

I expect 5, because the list [1,2,3,4,5,] which class Sub has is only 5 numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Hi furas your advice worked.  Thank you very much.
Hello Akash_Kumar, I revised the codes.  p = 0 if p == 0 were removed already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        self.inc(self.i)


    def inc(self, i):
        self.i += 1
        print(i)
        return i


class Sub(object):
    count = 0
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pp = B(count)
    for row in l:
        # print(row)
        pp.read()


k = Sub()
```

Output

```py
0
1
2
3
4
```

If you want 1,2,3,4,5 as output, change

```py
count=0
```

by

```py
count = 1
```

Your main problem was your confusion between i and self.i variables and the fact that inc was not defined into your B class.

**EDIT**

According to your comment, this should work.

```py
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        self.i = inc(self.i)


def inc(i):
    i += 1
    print(i)
    return i


class Sub(object):
    count = 0
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pp = B(count)
    for row in l:
        pp.read()


k = Sub()
```

Comment: Thank you fro your comments.
It worked.  I studied a lot.   i might confuse between i and self.i.
But, I intentionally took the def inc(i) out from class B.

class B is one of classes.  I will add other class C, class D and so on.
Those classes must be call to def inc().

So that I took def inc() out of class B.
The purpose of def inc is to collect the i number through other classes.]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 
I edited my answer to correspond to your needs. But I also noticed you probably got the correct answer in comments.

Comment: Hello I always thank you.There are a lot of things I have still not known.